# What does this set of django errors mean?

Tags: django, apache, apache2

My Apache2 log is spitting out these errors on my Ubuntu 10.04 server. When I hit the server I get Internal 500 Errors and the log has this:

```
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 281, in format
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     return df.format(format_string)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 187, in r
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 66, in force_unicode
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     s = unicode(s)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 206, in __unicode_cast
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 55, in ugettext
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     return real_ugettext(message)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 55, in _curried
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 36, in delayed_loader
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     return getattr(trans, real_name)(*args, **kwargs)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in ugettext
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 266, in do_translate
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 176, in translation
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     app = import_module(appname)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152]     __import__(name)
[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.152] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught 

ImportError while rendering: No module named mysite.website

[Mon Jul 19 07:40:11 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 192.168.1.152] Zlib: Compressed 620 to 383 : URL /admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PYTHONPATH` may not contain your project directory, or your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` may not contain 'mysite.website', at least from apache's point of view. Whatever user apache runs as for your website needs to have that set up for it, like in its `.profile`. Or if you're using `mod_python`, they need to be set up in the `.htaccess` or apache's `httpd.conf`. Or if you're using `mod_wsgi`, it needs to be in the wsgi setup file -- `passenger_wsgi.py` or the like -- whatever apache's module will be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You check the permissions on those files? (Obvious answer)