# Django Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django

I'm new at this and stuck. What would cause Django to run without error when I do python manage.py runserver but then throw Internal Server Error when I try to access it through the web? I have another project giving the Congratulations on your first Django-powered page, and I got the same result with the same .wsgi file initially with this project.

It wasn't until I tried to install this script in massivecoupon project that I got Internal Server Error:

http://github.com/coulix/Massive-Coupon---Open-source-groupon-clone

UPDATE:

I set Debug to True in settings.py and now I am getting the django error:

ViewDoesNotExist at /
Could not import massivecoupon.engine.views. Error was: No module named libs

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281433/what-does-this-set-of-django-errors-mean/3281632#3281632

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127109/django-admin-cookie-problem-on-mac

Answer (score 11):

You can use in command line

```
    [user]$ python manage.py check
```

Regards

Comment: I know you'll never read this, since it was your only post.  But thank you, I didn't know this existed.

Answer (score 7):

Quick answer: check your apache/tomcat access.log and error.log

Next, the other (not really dup) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281433/what-does-this-set-of-django-errors-mean/3281632#3281632) I quoted above may be a different situation, but I recommend looking into the same things:

> Your `PYTHONPATH` may not contain your project directory, or your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` may not contain 'mysite.website', at least from apache's point of view. Whatever user apache runs as for your website needs to have that set up for it, like in its `.profile`. Or if you're using `mod_python`, they need to be set up in the `.htaccess` or apache's `httpd.conf`. Or if you're using `mod_wsgi`, it needs to be in the wsgi setup file -- `passenger_wsgi.py` or the like -- whatever apache's module will be looking for.

Next:

- check if the files it needs to access are accessible by *what apache runs your django site as*
- make sure your database is accessible by *that user*
- and that the database setup/password is accessible by *that user*
- make sure you have `SITE_ID=1` set
- make sure that you have *a site record* added into the database

Answer (score 0):

First off check the Apache error log. If there is nothing in Apache error log, due to it being an internal error to your code or Django while handling a request, set DEBUG to True in Django site settings file and restart Apache so details of error display in the browser.